# How to return back to first menu switch case in Java?

Tags: java

This is my code. I'm stuck with switch case thing. I tried to finish my Java interface (console) homework. The idea is to make a login system.

I want to know how to return to 1st LOGIN menu (Main Menu) when user click LOGOUT / LOG OFF.

```
interface Login{
    public void validasi();
    public void cekData();
}

class DataLogin implements Login{
    private String namaUser1="mhs";
    private String pass1="mahasiswa";
    private String namaUser2="mahasiswa";
    private String pass2="pratikum";

    public void setName(String name, String name2){
        this.namaUser1 = name;
        this.namaUser2 = name2;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return namaUser1;
    }
    public String getName2(){
        return namaUser2;
    }
    public void setPsw(String pass, String pas2){
        this.pass1 = pass;
        this.pass2 = pas2;
    }
    public String getPsw(){
        return pass1;
    }
    public String getPsw2(){
        return pass2;
    }
```

This is my checkData method.

```
    public void cekData(){
        DataLogin u = new DataLogin();
        String Nama, Psw, log, mau;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Username : "); Nama=input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Password : "); Psw=input.nextLine();
            if (Nama.equalsIgnoreCase(u.getName())&&Psw.equalsIgnoreCase(u.getPsw())){
                System.out.println("(Login Success!)");
                System.out.println("-----------------");
             do{
                System.out.println("Selamat Datang, "+Nama+"!!");
                System.out.println("MENU PILIHAN");
                System.out.println("A. TEST KENDARAAN");
                System.out.println("B. LOG OFF");
                System.out.println("-----------------");
                System.out.print("Masukkan Pilihan Anda : ");log=input.nextLine();
                    switch(log){
                        case "A": case "a":
                            //SOME CODES.. NOT IMPORTANT
                            break;
                        case "B": case "b":
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("ERROR, Pilihan Tidak Tersedia");
                            break;
                    }

                    System.out.print("Mau Coba Lagi? [Y/T] = ");mau = e.next();
                }while(mau.equals("Y")||(mau.equals("y"))); 
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("(Login Gagal!)");
                System.out.println("Periksa Kembali Username dan Password Anda");
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            }

    }
}
```

This is my main menu.

```
 class TestLogin{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DataLogin u = new DataLogin();

        Scanner pil = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pilih;

        System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("MENU PILIHAN");
        System.out.println("A. LOGIN");
        System.out.println("B. EXIT");
        System.out.println("----------");

        System.out.print("Masukkan Pilihan Anda : ");pilih=pil.nextLine();
        switch(pilih){
            case "A":
            case "a":
                u.cekData();
                break;
            case "B":
            case "b":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
            {System.out.print("ERROR");}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your main menu in a separate method and call it again, when user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it, but this should work:-

1) Wrap the contents of your *main()* method into a loop.

2) In *cekData()*, if the user selects Log Out, instead of System.exit(), do a return.

After implementing the above, if the user selects Log Out, the thread will return to the main() method, which will loop around and display itself again.